# Loop through and copy key value pairs

Tags: python, regex, bash

Say for example, I have two text files containing the following:

**File 1**

> "key_one" = "String value for key one"
>   "key_two" = "String value for key two"
>   // COMMENT //
>   "key_three" = "String value for key two"

**File 2**

> // COMMENT
>   "key_one" = "key_one"
>   // COMMENT
>   "key_two" = "key_two"

Now, I want to loop through **File 1** and get out each key and string value (if its not a comment line). I then want to search **File 2** for the key and if its found, replace its string value with the string value from **File 1**

I'd guess using some regex would be good here but thats where my plan fails. I don't really have a great understanding of regex although I am getting better.

Heres the regex I came up with to match the keys: `"^\"\w*\""`
And heres the regex I was trying to match the string: `"= [\"a-zA-Z0-9 ]*"`

These may not be right or the best so feel free to correct me.

I am looking to complete this task using either a bash script or a python script. I did try in python to use the regex search and match functions but with little success.

Comment: you don't need regex if your file looks like that.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: for python: 
why not iterate through file 1 and create a dictionary, then
iterate through file 2 and replace values which can be found with the key in the dictionary

Comment: one way to parse all key/value pairs from file 1 to dict would be:
dict(re.findall(r"^\"(.*?)\"\s=\s\"(.*?)\"",file1.read(),re.MULTILINE))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using some of the tips given here I coded my own solution. It could probably be improved in a few places but I am pleased with myself for creating the solution without just copying and pasting someone else's answer. So, my solution:

```
import fileinput

translations = {}

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as fileOne:
    trans = fileOne.readlines()

    for line in trans:
        if (line.startswith("\"")):
            key, value = line.strip().split(" = ")
            translations[key] = value

for line in fileinput.input('file2.txt', inplace=True):
    if (line.startswith("\"")):
        key, value = line.strip().split(" = ")
        if key in translations:
            line = "{} = {}".format(key, translations[key])
    print line.strip()
```

I will give some upvotes to the useful answers still, if I can.

Comment: I will but it won't let me accept my own answer for 2 days.

Comment: Why the down vote? Would be helpful to have comments to go with it so I know where/what I can improve.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quote that I heard from somewhere: "If you have a problem and you try to solve it with regular expressions, you now have two problems".

What you want to achieve can be easily done with just a few inbuilt Python string methods such as `startswith()` and `split()`, without using any regex.

In short you can do the following:

```
For each line of File 1
    Check if it's a comment line by checking that it starts with '//'
    If not a comment line, split it to `key` and `value`
    Store the key/value in a dictionary

For each line of File 2
    Check if it's a comment line by checking that it starts with '//'
    If not a comment line, split it to `key` and `value`
    Check the dictionary to see if the key exists
    Output to the file as necessary
```

Comment: I like that quote! I usually try my best to stay away from regex and not sure why I didn't think of this "simpler" solution before.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary from the `FILE1` and then use it to replace values in `FILE2`

```
import fileinput
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'"(.*?)"\s+=\s+"(.*?)"')

with open('FILE1', 'r') as f:
    values = dict(pattern.findall(f.read()))

for line in fileinput.input('FILE2', inplace=True):
    match = pattern.match(line)
    if match:
        line = '"%s" = "%s"' % (match.group(1), values[match.group(1)])
    print line.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
```

def get_values(f):
    file1 = open(f,"r").readlines()
    values = {}
    for line in file1:
        if line[:2] !="//" and "=" in line:
            #print line
            key, value = line.split("=")
            #print key, value
            values[key]=value

```
return values
```

def replace_values(v1, v2):
    for key in v1:
        v = v1[key]
        if key in v2:
            v2[key]=v

file1_values = get_values("file1.txt")
file2_values = get_values("file2.txt")

print "BEFORE"
print pprint.pprint(file1_values)
print pprint.pprint(file2_values)

replace_values(file1_values, file2_values)

print "AFTER"
print pprint.pprint(file1_values)
print pprint.pprint(file2_values)

If the text files are that predictable then you could use something like that.

The above code will do what you want and replace the values with the following output:

```
        BEFORE
    {'"key_one" ': ' "String value for key one"\n',
     '"key_three" ': ' "String value for key two"',
     '"key_two" ': ' "String value for key two"\n'}

    {'"key_one" ': ' "key_one"\n', '"key_two" ': ' "key_two"'}

    AFTER
    {'"key_one" ': ' "String value for key one"\n',
     '"key_three" ': ' "String value for key two"',
     '"key_two" ': ' "String value for key two"\n'}

    {'"key_one" ': ' "String value for key one"\n',
     '"key_two" ': ' "String value for key two"\n'}
```